# Modal form checks errors but doesn't submit or submits but doesn't check errors

Tags: javascript, forms, modal-dialog

I'm learning Javascript online and I blocked on this validation modal form. Can anyone help?

So I have this form that I have to submit and I create a function to check inputs and it works and then when I submit it doesn't do anything.

Actually I think that I have to use an if statement with the "isFormValid" but I don't know where to insert it and how. I tried to insert this "isFormValid" all around the functions but because of it the form doesn't check the inputs anymore...

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const successPopupClose = document.querySelector(".close-success")
const errorMsg = document.querySelectorAll(".error");
const successIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".success-icon");
const failureIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".failure-icon");
let successMsg = document.getElementById("success-popup");

let firstName = document.getElementById("first");
let lastName = document.getElementById("last");
let email = document.getElementById("email");
let birthdate = document.getElementById("birthdate");
let checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
let quantity = document.getElementById("quantity")
let city = document.reserve.location;

let isFormValid = false;

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkInputs(); 
 
  // if(isFormValid) {
  //   modalbg.remove();
  //   successMsg.style.display = 'block';
})

function checkInputs() {

    // Validate first name
  if(firstName.value.trim() === ''){
    errorMsg[0].innerHTML = 'Veuillez entrer au moins 2 caractères';
    failureIcon[0].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[0].innerHTML = '';
    failureIcon[0].style.opacity = "0";
    successIcon[0].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = true;
  }

  // Validate last name
  if(lastName.value.trim() === ''){
    errorMsg[1].innerHTML = 'Veuillez entrer au moins 2 caractères';
    failureIcon[1].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[1].innerHTML = '';
    failureIcon[1].style.opacity = "0";
    successIcon[1].style.opacity = "1";
isFormValid = true;
  }
  
  // Validate email name
  if(email.value.trim() === ''){
    errorMsg[2].innerHTML = 'Vous devez entrer une address mail';
    failureIcon[2].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[2].innerHTML = '';
    failureIcon[2].style.opacity = "0";
    successIcon[2].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = true;
  }

  // Validate birthday
  if(birthdate.value === ''){
    errorMsg[3].innerHTML = 'Vous devez entrer une date de naissance';
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[3].innerHTML = '';
    successIcon[3].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = true;
  }

  // Validate quantity
  if(quantity.value === ''){
    errorMsg[4].innerHTML = 'Ce champ ne peut pas être vide';
    failureIcon[4].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[4].innerHTML = '';
    failureIcon[4].style.opacity = "0";
    successIcon[4].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = true;
  }

  // Validate location
  for (i=0; i<city.length; i++) {
    if(city[i].checked==true){
      errorMsg[5].innerHTML = '';
      isFormValid = true;
      break;
    }
    else {
     errorMsg[5].innerHTML = "Vous devez choisir une option";
     isFormValid = false
    //  return false;
    }
  }

  // Validate checkbox
  if(checkbox1.checked) {
    errorMsg[6].innerHTML = '';
    isFormValid = true;
  } else {
    errorMsg[6].innerHTML = "Vous devez accepter les conditions d'utilisation";
    isFormValid = false
  }
}
```

Comment: `form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  checkInputs(); 
  if(isFormValid) {
     modalbg.remove();
     successMsg.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else   e.preventDefault();
 })`

Comment: Feel free to delete the question. It does not have value for others since it was due to a logic error

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the problem was that I didn't have an if statement that would verify all the conditions

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const successPopupClose = document.querySelector(".close-success")
const errorMsg = document.querySelectorAll(".error");
const successIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".success-icon");
const failureIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".failure-icon");
let successMsg = document.getElementById("success-popup");

// eveny submit form
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkFirstName();
  checkLastName();
  checkEmail();
  checkBirthdate();
  checkQuantity();
  checkLocation();
  checkboxValidation();
  if(
  checkFirstName() && checkLastName() && checkEmail() && checkBirthdate() && checkQuantity() && checkLocation() && checkboxValidation()
  ) {
    modalbg.remove();
    successMsg.style.display = 'block';
  }
});


// check first name
function checkFirstName() {

  let firstName = document.getElementById("first-name");

  if(firstName.value.trim() === ''){
    errorMsg[0].innerHTML = 'Veuillez entrer au moins 2 caractères';
    failureIcon[0].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[0].innerHTML = '';
    failureIcon[0].style.opacity = "0";
    successIcon[0].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = true;
  }

// check last name
function checkLastName() {

  let lastName = document.getElementById("last-name");

    if(lastName.value.trim() === ''){
    errorMsg[1].innerHTML = 'Veuillez entrer au moins 2 caractères';
    failureIcon[1].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[1].innerHTML = '';
    failureIcon[1].style.opacity = "0";
    successIcon[1].style.opacity = "1";
isFormValid = true;
  }

// check email 
function checkEmail() {

  let emailData = document.getElementById("emailData");

   if(email.value.trim() === ''){
    errorMsg[2].innerHTML = 'Vous devez entrer une address mail';
    failureIcon[2].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[2].innerHTML = '';
    failureIcon[2].style.opacity = "0";
    successIcon[2].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = true;
  }

// check birthday
function checkBirthdate() {

  let birthdateData = document.getElementById("birthdateData");

  if(birthdate.value === ''){
    errorMsg[3].innerHTML = 'Vous devez entrer une date de naissance';
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[3].innerHTML = '';
    successIcon[3].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = true;
  }

// check quantity
function checkQuantity() {

  let quantityData = document.getElementById("quantityData");
  
    if(quantity.value === ''){
    errorMsg[4].innerHTML = 'Ce champ ne peut pas être vide';
    failureIcon[4].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = false;
  } else {
    errorMsg[4].innerHTML = '';
    failureIcon[4].style.opacity = "0";
    successIcon[4].style.opacity = "1";
    isFormValid = true;
  }
// check location
function checkLocation() {

  let locationData = document.getElementById("locationData");

    for (i=0; i<locationData.length; i++) {
    if(locationData[i].checked==true){
      errorMsg[5].innerHTML = '';
      isFormValid = true;
      break;
    }
    else {
     errorMsg[5].innerHTML = "Vous devez choisir une option";
     isFormValid = false
    }
  }

// check checkbox
function checkboxValidation() {

  let checkbox1Data = document.getElementById("checkbox1Data");

 if(checkbox1.checked) {
    errorMsg[6].innerHTML = '';
    isFormValid = true;
  } else {
    errorMsg[6].innerHTML = "Vous devez accepter les conditions d'utilisation";
    isFormValid = false
  }
}
```